# Rails 4 layout false needs refresh

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I have a rails 4 application which is using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem.

For some functionality, I need to render a view outside of the application layout since it has its own custom CSS and layout which must remain separate from bootstrap. The CSS file has been placed in the assets folder and the necessary line has been added to the assets.rb file. There is a view that's been created, which contains the document declaration, head and body.

A custom route and controller action were put in, and are working fine. However when the link is clicked to trigger this action, the page does not load the view correctly. The head still contains declarations for bootstrap files, despite them not existing in the view for this action. If the page is reloaded, it is displayed as intended.

Here is the controller code:

```
def qrcode
    render file: 'app/views/boxes/qrcode.html.erb', layout: false
end
```

This behaviour is uniform across Safari, Chrome and Firefox, both running locally and on Heroku.

## EDIT 2015-05-08

It turns out the bootstrap `application.js` is interfering with the CSS, however it is not declared in the custom layout and should not have been loaded at all.
The `application.js` is only declared in the application layout.

### Controller method

```
def qrcode
    @qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new("#{scan_url slug: @box.identifier}", size: 8).to_img.resize(400, 400).to_data_url
    render layout: "label"
end
```

### Label layout

Please forgive the amateurish HTML.

```
<div class="qrcode">
    <%= image_tag @qr, id: "qr" %>
</div>
<div class="label">
    From: Text Here<br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Text Here
    <br>
    To: Text Here<br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Text Here
</div>
```

## Another update

Turns out the `turbolinks.js` file was causing the unusual behaviour.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a separate layout to render specific action?

Comment: I'll give it a try shortly and let you know. I'd still say that the behaviour is unexpected.

Comment: No luck, even using a different layout with `layout: "layout_name"` still shows the same behaviour - the page displays correctly only after refresh.